# How to avoid screen with changing TextViews relayout?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a screen which basically consists of 2 parts

- upper is a hierarchical structure of multiple `LinearLayout`s with regularly changing `TextView`s,
- lower is a heavy for drawing custom view.

Currently the `TextView`s in the upper part have **`wrap_context`** set to their width, as a result every their change cause Android to relayout the whole page, including the hard for drawing custom view in the lower part.

**My question** - Is there another way to solve this problem except changing `layout_width` parameter for changing `TextView`s to constant value?

Comment: yes allow separate sizes based on screen size for upper and lower pars so lower part is independent is that what you are looking for use weightsum and layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

Create `LinearLayout` to be parent with vertical orienetation. Now create **two** children `LinearLayout` with vertical orienetation but with `layout_height` to 0dp for each and `layout_weight` to 1 for each respectively.